# Visual studio2010 CrystalReports authentication?

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I have two tables Customer and Contract Table

```
CustomerTable
    CustID(pk)
    CustName
    CompanyName
ContractTable
    ContractID(pk)
    CustID(fk)
    ContractDate
    ContractDuration
    TotalPayment
    TotalInstallment
    TotalCommission
```

I'm trying to create a crystal report to display customers of this month like this

```
    |CustID||CustName||ContractDuration||TotalPayment||TotalCommission|
    |      ||        ||                ||            ||               |
Total |200 ||                          ||  $20,000   ||  $200         |
```

After installing crystal reports for visual studio2010 from SAP i made crystal report using graphical interface and put this code in form_load event

```
ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
        cryRpt.Load("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\my documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\democrystal1\\democrystal1\\CrystalReport1.rpt");
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

when i run the project it prompt me to enter userid and password but i'm using windows authentication from SSMS what userid and password now i put in? and if i use a view to generate crystal report from it how that view looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to tell the report specifically when you load it to use Integrated Security like you want.  Here's a blog post I made a while back, scroll down to where the "ApplyNewServer" method is and that should get you started.

http://www.blakepell.com/Blog/?p=15

That method was taken out of a larger class.  You'll see that I was referencing properties for username/password, etc.  Using a method like this will loop through your report and all the sub reports and apply the connection info you specify.  I should really just turn this into an extension at some point.

Hope this puts you in the right direction, if not, let me know what additional questions you have.

Comment: I created some extension methods that make the ApplyNewServer easily accessible off the ReportDocument.  Thought I'd share as they maybe of use to you:  http://www.blakepell.com/Blog/?p=487

Comment: Hi p.Bell, please could you paste your extension methods here?, seems that your site is down.